# Create a collection given a number of times keeping the key

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a kind of dataset using laravel Collections, for this I'm using the "times" method:

```
function getValidData(int $amount): Collection
{
    return Collection::times($amount, function (int $number): array {
        $password = faker()->password(8, 12);

        return [
            "User #{$number}" => [
                'name' => faker()->firstName(),
                'email' => faker()->unique()->safeEmail(),
                'password' => $password,
                'password_confirmation' => $password
            ]
        ];
    });
}
```

However, the result is not as I expected:

```
[
    0 => [
        'User #1' => [
            'name' => 'ana',
            'email' => 'ana@email.com',
            'password' => '12345678',
            'password_confirmation' => '12345678' 
          ]
    ],
    1 => [
      'User #2' => [
            'name' => 'leo',
            'email' => 'leo@email.com',
            'password' => '3231232132',
            'password_confirmation' => '3231232132'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I was hoping it would be:

```
[
    'User #1' => [
        'name' => 'ana',
        'email' => 'ana@email.com',
        'password' => '12345678',
        'password_confirmation' => '12345678' 
    ],
    'User #2' => [
        'name' => 'leo',
        'email' => 'leo@email.com',
        'password' => '3231232132',
        'password_confirmation' => '3231232132'
    ]
]
```

I can solve this using `array_merge(...(Collection::times...))` but it seems a kinda off... Is there any way to solve this in a cleaner way using Collections?

Comment: it looks like you want 2d array into 1d

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to map the collection with new keys, you could do the following, using the [mapWithKeys() function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys).

**Example**

```
$users = collect(range(1, $amount))
  ->mapWithKeys( function($index) {
    $password = faker()->password(8, 12);
    
    return [sprintf("User #%d", $index) => [
        'name' => faker()->firstName(),
        'email' => faker()->unique()->safeEmail(),
        'password' => $password,
        'password_confirmation' => $password,
    ]];
});
```

This will run from 1 to the specified `$amount`. Example output with 3 users:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2016
  #items: array:3 [
    "User #1" => array:4 [
      "name" => "Garret"
      "email" => "aurelio03@example.com"
      "password" => "Vp=Et3!?w0"
      "password_confirmation" => "Vp=Et3!?w0"
    ]
    "User #2" => array:4 [
      "name" => "Genoveva"
      "email" => "hilda.bins@example.net"
      "password" => "W?miL1Kts"
      "password_confirmation" => "W?miL1Kts"
    ]
    "User #3" => array:4 [
      "name" => "Zella"
      "email" => "mmurray@example.net"
      "password" => "g8)"pYgjQ~"
      "password_confirmation" => "g8)"pYgjQ~"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You could also chain the `toArray()` method on the collection if you prefer an Array over a Collection.